# Why is the movie titled "Kiss of the Spider Woman"?

Tags: title, kiss-of-the-spider-woman

Movie is about government agency tries to extract the truth from Valentin Arregui using his homosexual prison mate Luis Molina.

Luis Molina tell 2 stories to Valentin Arregui: one is German movie & another is spider woman.

Valentin Arregui tells his love story to Luis Molina.

Then why is the movie titled *Kiss of the Spider Woman*?

Comment: It reminds me the movie *Kiss of the Dragon* in which I didn't see any dragon nor a kiss.

Comment: @AJ feel free & post a question here then.

Comment: Actually I don't need to. This is already mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss_of_the_Dragon#Origin_of_title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is a reference to a scene from the book between the two inmates, Molina and Valentin.

Molina tells Valentin about a a film he once saw, whether true or not, about a woman whose husband had been cheating on her and she had become afraid of instantly turning into a panther and devouring him if he kissed by her.

Later on, Valentin asks for a kiss from Molina before his parole release. The information from the FAQ reagarding this is below.

From [IMDB.com](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089424/faq):

> The title comes from a part in the book where Molina asks Valentin for
>   a kiss before he is paroled. Valentin (Raul Julia) asks Luis Molina
>   (William Hurt) whether he's afraid that he'll turn into a panther
>   woman (as in the first film Molina tells Valentin, where the panther
>   woman kills when she is kissed). Valentin says he is not the panther
>   woman but the spider woman, hence Kiss of the Spider Woman.